# ACF PRO selection field has no title

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

Since a short time I am not seeing any text in my ACF PRO rules field. I have no idea where I should start to debug this.

- WP: 5.3.2
- Timber: 1.14.0
- ACF PRO: 5.8.7

No other plugins.

[image]

The HTML seems to partially work...

```
<select id="acf_field_group-location-group_0-rule_0-value" class="" name="acf_field_group[location][group_0][rule_0][value]" data-ui="0" data-ajax="0" data-multiple="0" data-placeholder="Auswählen" data-allow_null="0">
 <option value="acf-options-gobal-settings"></option>
 <option value="acf-options-multilingual-settings"></option>
 <option value="acf-options-post-teaser"></option>
 <option value="acf-options-hero-header" selected="selected" data-i="0"></option>
 <option value="acf-options-featured-sites"></option>
 <option value="acf-options-news"></option>
 <option value="acf-options-events"></option>
 <option value="acf-options-classic-layout">Pagestyle: Classic Layout</option>
 <option value="timber-bulma-documentation">Documentation</option><option value="calendar-api">Calendar API</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You haven't put anything inside of your `<option>` elements. `<option value="acf-options-events">Lorem Ipsum Content</option>`

Comment: This gets generated by ACF PRO in the backend. That's exactly my issue, that the content is missing. I am not developing the output of this.

Comment: I have had this too - and if you inspect your code, you'll notice that you made a mistake somewhere. Check if you are missing titles/slugs somewhere.